# ES6/Typescript import: import * and names on a single line

Tags: typescript, import, ecmascript-6

How can I write this on 1 line?

```
import * as Express  from 'express';
import { Application, NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
```

Your Dan the Dev

Comment: `*` imports everything from `express`. I don't understand the need to import other modules separately

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`import` and `export` have restricted syntax that allows to statically analyze them:

As listed in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

> import defaultMember from "module-name";
>
> import * as name from "module-name";
>
> import { member } from "module-name";
>
> import { member as alias } from "module-name";
>
> import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";
>
> import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
>
> import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
>
> import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";
>
> import "module-name";

As it can be seen, there's no `import * as name, { member } from "module-name"`, so it isn't supported.

The reason why it isn't supported is because `import * as name, { member } from "module-name"` are interchangeable. It's either importing members one by one or as `name` namespace.

If both should be used for some reason, it should be:

```
import * as Express from 'express';
import { Application, NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
```

Or if exports are real variables and not types/interfaces, it can be:

```
import * as Express from 'express';
const { Application, NextFunction, Request, Response } = Express;
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the detailed answer, I will definitely take a closer look in the docs mentioned.

The last construct with const (which I've tried before) doesn't work unfortunately, but would be much more logical

Comment: I added a clarification. I assume that's because they are interfaces and not real classes, aren't they? So no, const destructuring won't make sense because there's nothing to destructure. In this case the first option is the correct one, and btw, it's quite conventional to not import the interfaces separately, because `foo: Express.NextFunction` reads cleaner and this way interfaces aren't confused with classes, even if they don't have `I` suffix.

Comment: Yes, they are all interfaces :)

Comment: Thanks for commenting on this