# How to inline useState when importing react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using the following code to import `useState`:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react'
```

I would like to know if there is a way to place it one line, for example I tried:L

```
import * as React, {useState} from 'react'
```

but it does not work.

Please let me know thanks!

Comment: why -1? please add a comment I can improve my question

Comment: Just remove `* as `. It should look like this `import React, { useState } from "react"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually works for me:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
```

Named and default import

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry, you can't put both `import * as React, {useState}` in a single line. If you want to import `React and {useState}` in a single line then import React directly - remove `* as`**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

Please refer to this - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

In the first example, they have imported both in the single line.

**why `import * as React, {useState} from 'react'` is not allowed?**

As listed in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import):

```
import defaultMember from "module-name";

import * as name from "module-name";

import { member } from "module-name";

import { member as alias } from "module-name";

import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";

import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";

import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";

import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";

import "module-name";
```

As it can be seen, there's no `import * as name, { member } from "module-name"`, so it isn't supported.

The reason why it isn't supported is because `import * as name, { member } from "module-name"` are interchangeable. It's either importing members one by one or as name namespace.

If both should be used for some reason, it should be:

```
import * as Express from 'express';
import { Application, NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
```

Or if exports are real variables and not types/interfaces, it can be:

```
import * as Express from 'express';
const { Application, NextFunction, Request, Response } = Express;
```

Reference - [ES6/Typescript import: import * and names on a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867553/es6-typescript-import-import-and-names-on-a-single-line)

Answer (score 0):

import React, { useState } from "react";

Here "React" will be default import and {useState} will be the name of hook, which is not included in default export in React library.

You can use the useState even if you have not imported the hook explicitly by **React.useState**

Answer (score 0):

just add `"esModuleInterop": true` to tsconfig.json